# MSChart Gaussian Scale

Tags: c#, axis, scaling, gaussian, mschart

I am currently coding a webservice so I can create a normal probability plot with MSChart, save it, export it to a PNG and finally print it on a report for a user.

My problem is that for this kind of graph, the Y Axis Scale is kinda strange. Indeed, you have the same space between 1 and 5 - 5 and 20 - 20 and 50 - 50 and 80 - 80 and 95 - 95 and 99 ; and a slightly different one between 0.01 and 1 - 99 and 99.99.

I tried the Logarithmic scale which doesn't fit my purpose and I can't find any solution on how to do that.

You can see below what my Y Axis scale should look like (made with Minitab).

[image]

Comment: I doubt you can make the chart do this. most likely you may have to a) scale the data __and__ b) use customlabels.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?